# Multiply-with-carry in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, random

The following code snippet is a direct translation of the [multiply-with-carry algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) which can be found in various places (I took [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25172/Simple-Random-Number-Generation) as a reference).

```
public class MultiplyWithCarryRandomGenerator
{

 struct Static {
    static var m_w:UInt = 521748629
    static var m_z:UInt = 762436069
 }

 class var m_w:UInt{get{return Static.m_w } set{Static.m_w = newValue}};
 class var m_z:UInt{get{return Static.m_z } set{Static.m_z = newValue}};

 private class func GetUint()->UInt
 {
    m_z = 36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16);
    m_w = 18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16);
    return (m_z << 16) + m_w;
 }

 public class func GetUniform()->Double
 {
    return   ((Double(GetUint()) + 1.0) * 2.32830643545449e-10);
 }
}
```

Within XCode playground the uniform distribution remains somewhere between 0 and 40K while it should be in the interval (0,1). 
Is there an obvious mistake in my code or an artifact of iOS, the playground...?

[image: Sample uniform array plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two differences between C# (the language of that example) and Swift that are causing this problem. The first is that a C# `uint` is a 32-bit unsigned integer, while a `UInt` in Swift is an unsigned integer matched to the architecture of the system it's executing on, which means in most cases today `UInt` is a 64-bit unsigned integer. Since all the constants in your code are geared toward 32 bits, simply change all the `UInt` declarations to `UInt32` and you're halfway there.

The second difference is that addition operations overflow automatically in C# when working with unsigned integers, while in Swift an overflow crashes. You aren't seeing an issue yet, since you're using 32-bit constants with a 64-bit datatype, but after switching to `UInt32` you'll start crashing on the overflow in this line:

```
return (m_z << 16) + m_w;
```

Swift provides an alternate set of operators, prefixed by `&`, that silently allow overflow—using `&+` in that line solves the issue:

```
return (m_z << 16) &+ m_w;
```

And now you get the graph you were hoping for:

[image]

Comment: Minor nitpicking: C does not have a `uint` type, and `unsigned int` is not necessarily 32-bit (even if it is on most current architectures). The referenced code is written in C#, which defines `uint` as a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: That's deep, not the kinda info/solution I'd have found in the docs easily. You suggest that the algorithm doesn't work with int64, right? An intrinsically 32bit piece of magic?

Comment: @FrancoisVanderseypen Not at all—the algorithm is likely fine, but since it depends on the value rolling over, a different set of constants would be needed for 64 bits.